# -bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied

Tags: storage

This error recently appeared on my Raspberry Pi. I get this error when I try to autocomplete folder paths. It won't autocomplete commands at all. I don't get this error when I'm logged in as root.

When I do `df -i` I get:

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root      399840 157845 241995   40% /
devtmpfs       117383    394 116989    1% /dev
tmpfs          118466      1 118465    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          118466    570 117896    1% /run
tmpfs          118466      8 118458    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          118466     10 118456    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6      0      0      0     - /boot
tmpfs          118466      4 118462    1% /run/user/1000
```

When I do `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       5.9G  5.7G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.5M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   65M   21M   45M  32% /boot
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

So it seems like my root is out of storage. I already removed files and uninstalled packages but nothing seems to change the outcome of `df -h`.

Please help, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

`du -smh /` gives me:

```
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/task/2667/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/task/2667/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
5.7G    /
```

Comment: Can you edit to append the output of `du -smh /`?  Also, which filesystem are you using and have you made any changes to permissions lately?

Comment: `du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/task/2667/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/task/2667/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2667/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
5.7G /`


I'm using ext2/ext3

And yes, I've recently added a new user which I gave sudo permissions, I also gave that user access to some folders

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before but the solution in my case turned out to be `sudo apt-get clean` aftwer which `df -h` gave the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       5.9G  5.2G  373M  94% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  7.8M  455M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   65M   21M   45M  32% /boot
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Thanks for your time and input, Schives.