# Cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, here-string

*[Note: [This similar Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365984/bash-cannot-create-temp-file-for-here-document-permission-denied#365989) concerns the same bash error message. It's been marked a duplicate of [this other Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux).  But because I found a very different source for this error, I will answer my own Q below.]*

This previously working bash script line

```
while ... do ... done <<< "$foo"
```

one day started producing this error message:

> cannot create temp file for here-document: Permission denied

Comment: In my case it was enabled [IMA](https://sourceforge.net/p/linux-ima/wiki/Home/) (`ima_policy=appraise_tcb` kernel parameter) with combination of `/tmp` not being `tmpfs`. But this is not really a common case :).

Answer (score 14):

In my case I altered the `/tmp` directory default permissions (I think I've changed by mistake to 0777).

The solution was to revert it back to the default `/tmp` permission, which is 1777 in octal (1=sticky bit, 7=R+W+X).

So in a nutshell `sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp` should fix the problem.

Comment: I can see where that would indeed cause issues.  Yes, the sticky bit is important for /tmp.

Comment: You probably don't want the `-R` flag. No reason to change everyone's files below `/tmp` to be read-write-executable by everyone. Some of those files are sensitive to the security of your users.

Answer (score 12):

I had added **`umask 777`** before the here string.  After removing the umask, the error went away.  So lesson learned:  There is a temporary file created for a here string (`<<<`), and this is related to a here document (`<<`), and you must have an appropriate umask set for these to work.

Comment: Interesting indeed. +1 See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166292/bash-cannot-create-temp-file-for-here-document-no-space-left-on-device/166295

Comment: It also affects zsh and mksh, not ksh93 nor tcsh. Not dash, rc, es, nor yash either but that's because they use pipes instead of temp files.

Comment: In the case of ksh93 and tcsh, it works because they open the file only once in read+write mode, write the data and then seek back to the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

my personal experience with this problem was with `umask` binary notation, just like @eliptical-view. I supposed that writing:

```
umask 0644
```

would give me read and write access to the files I created, what's wrong

After I changed the `umask` to be

```
umask 0022
```

the error disappeared.

Actually, the binary notation should be understood as a binary complement.

So, in the `umask`'s mask below when one writes `0` for the file owner, this user will have total access to the files he or she creates. The value `2` means the 2nd bit is masked, what means in this case, by default the other users will not be allowed to write to the files the file owner creates.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and correction, @Paulo Tomé. Indeed, it is usual (and clear) to use octal notation in `umask`, for precisely three bits are involved in Posix file permissions -- for the owner, one of his or her groups, and everybody else.

Comment: You're welcome. ;)